# Expect extra characters after close-quote

Tags: gitlab, expect

I'm getting an error

```
extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn ssh-add <(echo -e "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
 DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,2AB77A7C6E344A120BA00670A3CAB833

 AM57TuHYLo..."
```

When using expect and spawn to add ssh key with passphrase.
This is my script:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
expect -c "spawn ssh-add <(echo -e \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\\r\"); expect \"Enter passphrase\"; send \"$SSH_PASSPHRASE\\r\"; expect eof;"
```

I also tried many combinations when echoing the ssh private key:

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
echo \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\"
echo -e \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\"
echo '$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'
echo '$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got bash syntax in the expect body (I don't see why you think you need a process substitution there). When dealing with quoting hell in bash, a here-document is quite handy

```
expect <<END_EXPECT
    spawn ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    expect "Enter passphrase"
    send "$SSH_PASSPHRASE\r"
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```